# Ajax response is going wrong way

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, zend-framework, post

Task: when i choose from select tag customer(i have customer_id), it's must get request into DB and return all customer field. And then it's must automatic fill some input's. I try to make ajax+jQuery. Ajax is good. It's working now!

Here's JS:

I figure this out:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#customer_load').change(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?= $this->url(array('action' => 'ajax', 'controller' => 'baza')) ?>',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                    // list of request parameters 
                    'customer_id':  $(this).attr('value')
            },
            success: function(data) {
                    //alert(data.current_discount);
                    $('#extra_discount').val(data.extra_discount);
                    $('#current_discount').val(data.current_discount);
                    $('#customer_number').val(data.customer_id);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

PHP init:

```
$this->_helper->AjaxContext()->addActionContext('add', 'json')->initContext('json');
```

Ajax action:

```
$id= $this->_getParam('customer_id');
$result = $this->_customers->fetchSelected($id);
$this->view->customers = $result;
$this->_helper->json($result);
```

html:

```
<select name="customer_id" id="customer_load" style="width:300px;">
   <option value="0">Выберите заказчика</option>
      ?php foreach ($this->customers as $cus): ?>
   <option value="<?= $cus['customer_id'] ?>"" <?php if ($cus['customer_id'] == $this->form_data['customer_id']) echo "selected"; ?> ><?= $cus['lastname'] . " " . $cus['name'] ?></option>
   <?php endforeach; ?>
    <option value="new" onclick="NewCustomer()">Новый заказчик</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Are you using mod-rewrite of some kind in order to resolve the given URL in your Ajax call '/add'?

Comment: temporarily disabled `isXmlHttpRequest` check in controller and test you ajax action directly in the browser first. Once you get it working add safety conditions and implement you ajax calls.

Comment: thanks for advice Alex, i change url to '/baza/add', but in my firebug it's 
POST http://www.voskmodel.dev/baza/add 200 OK    65ms
i guess customer_id sending nowhere

Comment: temporarily change `$this->getRequest()->getPost` to `$this->_getParam` and request in browser like this `www.mysite.com/controller/action/customer_id/123`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from your post it's hard to understand if the problem is on client or server side...
In your first example you are not using `customer_id` in your ajax request and you do not need to cast the value to `Number` in javascript.

Use AJAX Request Below:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
     url: <?= $this->url(array('action' => 'add', 'controller' => 'baza')) ?>,
     type: 'POST',
     dataType: 'json',
     data: {
        // list of request parameters 
        'customer_id': $('select[name=customer_id] option:selected').val(),
     },
     success: function(results){
         // analyze your response and add custom logic
         console.debug(result);
     }
   });
});
```

As per your PHP code, you are overcomplicating things. 
Add your checks at the top of action and comment them out while you are trying to get it working (this way you can test `baza/add` directly in browser), once you get it working uncomment and test. Use [JSON view helper](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.controller.actionhelpers.html#zend.controller.actionhelpers.json) to output the json.

```
   public function addAction() 
   {
        // checks/validation/etc

        // do some processing...               
        $result = $this->_customers->fetchSelected($id);

        // Send the JSON response:
        $this->_helper->json($result);
   }
```